# Check a field in the User table before login?

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, bcrypt

I am migrating encryption methods to an already existing ~200 users database to bcrypt.

What I want to do is when a user who is using the normal login form submits the request, the app will then query the database and see if the user is flagged '1' in the 'User.flag' field. If he is flagged 1 then he will be sent to another login form where he can enter in a new password to get it encrypted the new way.

If the user is flagged 0 then he just logs in as normal.

For the first part, I will not even be using there old password to confirm that they are the real users, I will simply only match the username they input to the username in the database, nothing to do with the password. The reason being is that it seems much more simple then having to implement my old encryption method just for ~200 users that are extremely unlikely to guess each others usernames.

Does anyone have any examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is use only one form with ID and PASSWORD.

When the user submit that form you then check if he's on the old encryption system, check his password with that old encryption, and if it matches you redirect him to the change password page, or just take his password and update his password in the database directly with the new encryption.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to perform the 'check' before the login is sent. I don't know how to check if the user is flagged, so that's what i'm trying to figure out

Comment: So your question would be how to do that without reloading the page ?

Comment: `that are extremely unlikely to guess each others usernames.` is an optimistic assumption. What if I ran a brute force attack against your password check with some rainbow lists and set new passwords on all of your users? I recommend to have the user logged in properly and then force him to change his old password for security reasons! That would eliminate your problem, besides.

Comment: No, i'm asking how do I code it so that when a user logs in it checks his Flag, and depending on the flag value it either redirects him to another page, or it logs him in normally.

Axel; this website is a very small thing, and in closed beta, that is completely unlikely to happen

Comment: Why don't you use the more secure and easier way I told you instead ? That will avoid people resetting other people's password because unlikely doesn't mean impossible. It will also act just like you want by resetting the password of the guy.

Comment: Well yes, if I could, I would do it that way. But the problem is I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I don't get your problem lol. You get the mail and password in the $_POST datas, you query your database to see if the user with the mail $_POST['mail'] is 0, if yes you go to login through your new encryption system, if not you login with your old one, if the login/password is good you take his password in the $_POST data, store the new hash of his password over the old one in the database and set his flag to 0. Then his password will be "newly encrypted" and his flag will correspond to this new state.

Comment: I'm not looking for the method how to do it, i'm looking for someone to suggest some articles on how to actually CODE it, or an example of the code, or something like that. I just don't know the proper syntax for it. I am new to cakePHP so I don't know how to actually do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//AppController.php
public function beforeFilter(){

   $this->_new_encryption_check();

}

private function _new_encryption_check(){
    if ($this->request->data && $this->action == 'login'){
        $this->loadModel('User');
        //find user by whatever their login name is
        $user = $this->User->findByEmail($this->request->data['User']['email']);
        if ($user && $user['User']['flag'] == '1'){
            $this->Session->setFlash('You must reset your password for security purposes.', 'flash/error');
            $this-redirect('newEncryption/forPassword/url');
        }
    }

}
```

Just make sure you have them verify their old password before you allow them to reset to the new encryption in your new login controller function.